# How to query a sub-element of the design document in CouchDB?

Tags: database, nosql, couchdb, couchdb-mango

I have a couchdb database containing about 900 documents, with an average size of ~600KB. Each document is quite complex containing thousands of elements with 5-6 levels of depth. to speed up data search, I extracted some top-level information using a design document, where one of the entries look like this

```
{
    "id": "doc1",
    "key": "doc1",
    "value": {
        "name": "title",
        "length": 149085,
        "readme": "... ",
        "info": {
            "version": "1.0.0",
            "license": "CC0",
            "authors": [
                "...",
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to query the `value.info.version` field in the design document with a hope that this would be much faster than writing a `_find` command to do the ad-hoc search from the entire database. However, from reading the design document documentation, I wasn't able to find an API to retrieve subelement from the generated design document.

can this be done? or `_find` is the only way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this without resorting to a `_find` is to create a new view that emits whatever field you want to filter (search) by as they `key`. Then you can use `startkey`/`endkey` to filter out only those docs from the view.

Comment: thanks, can you help me understand the difference between the key and the value? the key seems to be queryable, but value is not - should I place all emitted information in the key and leave value null?what's the downside doing this? moreover - key must be an array or it can be an object? if it is an object, what is the format for startkey/endkey? I am not able to find documentation on this.

Comment: Well, you can only filter lexically from a start to an end, so adding all info to the key isn't going to help. Generally I have a view for every field I want to search/filter by.

Comment: ...and your key can be any JSON object, but it only makes sense storing so much info in there. It needs to be a straight hierarchy, otherwise it won't be filterable lexically.